# input Email не меняет background-color при выборе элемента из списка

Tags: html, css, email, input, background-color

при нажатии на ввод электронной почты появляется список сообщений, которые уже имеются в браузере, я выбрал один, и цвет фона ввода меняется на белый.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.form__input {
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #151515;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova";
    border: none;
    padding: 15px 22px;
    width: 356px;
    color: #6F6F6F;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #ffffff11, 4px 4px 4px #00000044;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #ffffff11, 4px 4px 4px #00000044; 
}
```

```html
<div class="form__grup">
<input type="email" class="form__input input__good" placeholder=" ">
<label class="form_label">email</label>
</div>
```

В инспекторе появился вот такой код:

```
input:-internal-autofill-selected {
appearance: menulist-button;
background-image: none !important;
background-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(232, 240, 254), rgba(70, 90, 126, 0.4)) !important;
color: fieldtext !important;}
```

я его нигде не прописывал и как убрать его не знаю

Если в `<label class="form_label">Email</label>` английскую букву E Поменять на русскую E то всё работает нормально, но список с выбором адреса электронной почты не отображается при клике на ввод